# Spring Cloud Dataflow Add Oracle Driver to CLASSPATH

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow

We have a requirement to create Streams in Spring Cloud Dataflow that retrieve data from an Oracle database.  However, as documented, Dataflow doesn't come pre-packaged with the Oracle drivers.  We're currently deploying the application with a custom Helm chart to Kubernetes.  We've tried the following:

1. Added the jar to the /lib/ directory
2. Added the jar to another directory and set the CLASSPATH environment variable to ".:/libs/ojdbc10.jar"
3. Tried to specify the location in the LOADER_PATH variable

All the documentation suggests that we more than likely need to roll our own version of Spring Cloud Dataflow.  However, if we do that we will lose the ability to utilize the Kubernetes default deployer.  And my employer is adamantly opposed to doing much development.

Is there a way to add the Oracle driver to the classpath WITHOUT rolling our own version of Spring Cloud Dataflow?  Is there any directory out there that will dynamically add the driver to Spring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common approach at customers/community is that you pull the GA-released tag from the SCDF repo, add your desired licensed DB driver dependency, and build it for your use.

If that is impossible for your ORG, there's another procedure in [our docs](https://docs.pivotal.io/scdf-k8s/1-2/configuring-installation-values.html) — see under `Add a JDBC Driver (Optional)` section.

Comment: We just need the driver injected into the jdbc stream app honestly.  I'm assuming we need to package the driver into the whole stack to accomplish this.  Our batch jobs that use Oracle jdbc all come pre-built with the driver on the classpath so it's kind of a new issue.  We've been instructed to abandon the batch jobs and simply use Streams to accomplish the same thing.  However, the requirement we were given was to avoid customizing any of the images or writing any custom code.  I'll give this a shot thanks!